# I have published my app in google play store but is not visible for samsung galaxy note5 and nexus 6

Tags: android, screen-density

I have a galaxy note 5 and I cannot install the application but it works on other phones and tablets.

I think it might have to do with the fact that phone has quad hd screen but other seems to be working fine. I don't know what else could be different. I

went to google developer console and note 5 isn't even on the list of all devices.

```
supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />


    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />


    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all x-large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />


    <!-- Special case for new phones with large screens 5"+ and Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="213" android:screenSize="large" />


    <!-- For xxhdpi devices you can use 480 as an int value -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- For xxxhdpi devices you can use 640 as an int value -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="xlarge" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: This looks fine. Did u mention any max sdk support in your manifest or build.gradle file ?

Comment: no how to mention max sdk support ?please give me a idea

Comment: there will 2 attribute android:minSdkVersion="" android:maxSdkVersion="" if havent mentioned it then it will not be a problem

Comment: i have mention only  minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23 in gradle file but maxSdk i cannot mention yet...please give me idea about how to solve above problem

Answer (score 0):

just try with adding this piece of code

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

```
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen
    android:screenDensity="ldpi"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="mdpi"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="hdpi"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
    android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
```

This code involves everything even tablets [refer this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) to exclude tablets

Comment: I havent checked for note5. But when i had same issue this solved the problem.